# Yaml warning in PyCharm during execution

Tags: python, pycharm, yaml, warnings

Can anyone help with the reason why this is happening?

`YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details`.

```
  logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.load(open('logging.yml', 'r')))
```

Comment: Warnings are not Errors. It's just telling you that you're using an old version of YAML and the function you're calling will not work if you update, so if someone is using a newer YAML version it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warnings are not Errors. It's just telling you that you're using a function of YAML that will be removed in a future update and that function will not work if you update, so if someone is using a newer YAML version it will not work.

The [link you referred to](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation#why-is-this-deprecated) talks about that exactly, how to solve it and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. I was using yaml.load() and when I changed it to yaml.safe_load() the warning went away. There's also a whole discussion in github about it: https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-utils/issues/462

Comment: @DanielaGarciaToranzo if I helped you then please accept `Tick` my solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was using yaml.load() and when I changed it to yaml.safe_load() the warning went away. There's also a whole discussion in github about it: github.com/bioconda/bioconda-utils/issues/462 –