# FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated

Tags: python

i am getting the following FutureWarning:

```
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  self.commission_matrix[np.meshgrid(indexes, indexes, indexing='ij', sparse=True)] = self.trading_fee[
```

How can I formulate

```
    for exc_name in self.exchanges.keys():
        indexes = [index for cur_name, index in self.currency2index.items() if exc_name in cur_name]
        self.commission_matrix[np.meshgrid(indexes, indexes, indexing='ij', sparse=True)] = self.trading_fee[
            exc_name]
```

so that it avoids this error? I use pychem and no other topic on this FutureWarning could help me. The FutureWarning doesn't affect my results but I want to know how I can bypass this warning.
Thank you very much

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391413/yaml-warning-in-pycharm-during-execution/66391479#66391479

Comment: What are `exc_name` and `self.trading_fee`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will get rid of the warning:

```py
   for exc_name in self.exchanges.keys():
        indexes = [index for cur_name, index in self.currency2index.items() if exc_name in cur_name]
        self.commission_matrix[tuple(np.meshgrid(indexes, indexes, indexing='ij', sparse=True))] = self.trading_fee[
            exc_name]
```